# Size of a sharepoint web application

Tags: sharepoint

How do you figure out the current size of the sharepoint web application? Better yet, the size of a site collection or a subsite.

I am planning to move a site collection from one farm to another. I need to plan the storage capacity first.

Comment: What version of Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are using SharePoint 2007 then open Site Actions / Site Settings / Storage Space Allocation.

Or from the command line:

STSADM.exe -o enumsites -url http://path_to_site

STSADM is located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\

More [on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+size+of+site+collection).